# SQLAlchemy: Vector Search on the keys of JSONB column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am implementing vector search in my Sqlalchemy Model.

The table is as follows:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    description = db.Column(postgresql.JSONB, server_default='{}')
    search_vector = db.Column(TSVectorType('title', 'description', nullable=True)  # created the search vector here
```

Now, the search should be based on 2 fields: **'title'** and **'description'**.

The **'description'** field is JSONB type, so I have used the below function in my DB migration file to implement search on that column-

```
def upgrade():
    vectorizer.clear()
    conn = op.get_bind()
    register_composites(conn)
    op.add_column('my_model', sa.Column('search_vector', sa.Text, nullable=True), schema='my_schema')
    metadata = MetaData(schema='my_schema')

    @vectorizer(postgresql.JSONB)
    def data_vectorizer(column):
        return sa.cast(column, sa.Text)

    sync_trigger(conn, 'my_model', 'search_vector', ['title', 'description'], metadata=metadata)
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_my_model_search_vector'), 'my_model', ['search_vector'], unique=False,
                schema='my_schema')
```

*The search is working fine.*

**Problem:**

The value of *description* field is something like: `{'section': 'abc', 'item': 'xyz'}`.

Now when I search, I want a record to be searched if the value of `section` is `'abc'`. But if I am searching with the value - `'section'`, then also it is showing the record. This is because the value - `{'section': 'abc', 'item': 'xyz'}` is getting *cast* to a string completely and hence the keyword `'section'` is also getting searched which I do not want.

Any solution where only `abc` is searched and **not** `section` ?

Thanks in advance.